# Preprocessor for haskell source: is cpp the only option?

Tags: haskell, c-preprocessor

I can see from plenty of Q&As that `cpp` is the usual preprocessor for Haskell source; but that it isn't a good fit for the job. What other options are there?

Specifically:

- Haskell syntax is newline-sensitive and space/indent-sensitive -- unlike `C`, so `cpp` just tramples on whitespace;
- `'` in Haskell might surround a character literal, but also might be part of an identifier (in which case it won't be paired) -- but `cpp` complains if not a char literal;
- `\` gets a trailing space inserted -- which is not a terrible inconvenience, but I'd prefer not.

I'm trying to produce a macro to generate an `instance` from parameters for a `newtype` type and corresponding data constructor. It needs to generate both the instance head and constraints and a method binding. By just slotting the constructors into an instance skeleton.

(Probably Template Haskell could do this; but it seems rather a large hammer.)

Comment: Some projects use custom preprocessors, but I don't think there's one that's really established. See, the whole idea of _preprocessing plaintext code_ is seen as awkward. It's much safer to preprocess on the AST level, and the tool for that is Template Haskell. CPP is really just meant for very simple stuff like swapping out different functions depending on the version of a package that Cabal is using.

Comment: `What other options are there?` You can use _any_ other preprocessor in existence, it's just text. Your questions is too broad, or offtopic, because you are asking for third-party recommendations. `I'm trying to produce a macro` Great - so ask about that. "How to produce a macro that....?" and specify input arguments and the output you want to get.

Comment: Make sure `DerivingVia` doesn't already fit the bill before reaching for preprocessors or TH.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of code that causes a problem with `'` and CPP? I just tried https://gist.github.com/josephcsible/f9e7a60ad017d804c3e517377c278388 and it worked fine.

Comment: @Joseph, yes it "works" in the sense it does pass through the `'` and the resulting Haskell compiles; but there's a warning for every `'` -- which'll get very tedious for dozens of occurrences, and might hide genuine errors.

Comment: @AntC I compiled the code in the gist I linked with `-Weverything` and didn't get any warnings about that. Can you include the exact command you're running and the warnings you get?

Comment: `warning: missing terminating ' character` for every appearance of non-paired `'`. (And I want to put `'`s in the names embedded in the expansion, not just in params: `#define puts putStrln hello'world`.

Comment: @AntC I just updated my gist to do that too, and I still don't see that warning. What's the exact command line you're using when you get it?

Comment: The warning is coming from `cpp`, not from GHC. I'm running `cpp` from the command line without trying to compile -- so I can see its output. `> cpp myfile.hs myfileout.hs`

Answer (score 4):

[`cpphs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cpphs) seems to be just about enough for my (limited) purposes. I'm adding this answer for the record; an answer suggesting `cpphs` (and some sensible advice to prefer Template Haskell) was here and then gone.

But there's some **gotchas** that meant at first sight I'd overlooked how it helped.

Without setting any options, it behaves too much like `cpp` to be helpful. At least:

- It doesn't complain about unpaired `'`. Indeed you can `#define dit '` and that will expand happily.
- More generally, it doesn't complain about any nonsense input: it grimly carries on and produces some sort of output file without warning you about ill-formed macro calls.
- It doesn't insert space after `\`.
- By default, it smashes together multiline macro expansions, so tramples on whitespace just as much.
- Its tokenisation seems to get easily confused between Haskell vs `C`. specifically, using `C`-style comments `/* ... */` seems to upset not only those lines, but a few lines below. (I had a `#define` I wanted to comment out; should have used Haskell style comments `{- ... -}` -- but then that appears in the output.)
- The calling convention for macros is `C` style, not Haskell. `myMacro(someArg)` -- or `myMacro (someArg)` seems to work; but not `myMacro someArg`. So to embed a macro call inside a Haskell expression probably needs surrounding the lot in extra parens. Looks like `(LISP)`.
- A bare macro call on a line by itself `myInstance(MyType, MyConstr)` would not be valid Haskell. The dear beastie seems to get easily confused, and fails to recognise that's a macro call.
- I'm nervous about `#` and `##` -- because in `cpp` they're for stringisation and catenation. I did manage to define `(##) = (++)` and it seemed to work; `magicHash#` identifiers seemed ok; but I didn't try those inside macro expansion.

**Remedies**

(The docos don't make this at all obvious.)

- To get multi-line output from a multi-line macro def'n, and preserving spaces/indentation (yay!) needs option `--layout`. So I have my `instance` definition validly expanded and indented.
- If your tokenisation is getting confused, maybe `--text` will help: this will "treat input as plain text, not Haskell code" -- although it does still tolerate `'` and `\` better. (I didn't encounter any downsides from using `--text` -- the Haskell code seemed to get through unscathed, and the macros expanded.)
- If you have a `C`-style comment that you don't want to appear in output, use `--strip`.
- There's an option `--hashes`, which I imagine might interact badly with `magicHash#`.
- The output file starts with a header line `#line ...`. The compiler won't like that; suppress with `--noline`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Template Haskell is the most perfect tool for this purpose.  It is the standard set of combinators for constructing correct Haskell source code.  After that there is `GHC.Generics`, which might allow you to write a single instance that would cover any type which is an instance of `Generic`.